# Can't delete Parenthesis in IntelliJ/Cursive

Tags: intellij-idea, clojure, cursive

I'm using IntelliJ/Cursive to write Clojure.
I found out that the only way to erase parenthesis is to totally erase the content inside them, and only then, the parenthesis can be deleted.
For example, let's say that I have the following code:

```
(list)
```

and I want to delete only the opening parenthesis. Once I hit backspace on the opening parenthesis, the IDE ignores this act. Only when I erase the word "list", the parenthesis can be deleted.

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: have you structural editing enabled? see the fine manual https://cursive-ide.com/userguide/paredit.html

Comment: I looked at your link and found the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 24):

From the [docs](https://cursive-ide.com/userguide/paredit.html):

> Structural editing comes enabled for Clojure code by default. If you don't like it, you can turn it off at *Settings→Editor→General→Smart Keys→Use structural editing*. If you'd like to toggle it on and off quickly, you can use the widget in the status bar at the bottom of the screen, or you can use the *Edit→Structural Editing→Toggle Structural Editing Style* action. If you find yourself doing that a lot you can even assign a shortcut key to the action.

Comment: Moved to IntelliJ→Preferences→Editor→General→Smart Keys→Clojure in latest version.

Answer (score 4):

You can delete the parenthesis while remaining in structural editing mode by selecting/highlighting it first with your cursor or shift+arrow.  You'll then need to manually remove the corresponding close parenthesis too.

Answer (score 2):

There is another way to remove parenthesis, using the structural editing command "Splice Sexp". You can also use slurping and barfing to manipulate the parenthesis to the order that you want.

Answer (score 0):

Recently was moved to Edit > Structural Editing > Toggle Structural Editing Style