# Cannot type single bracket or parentheses in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, clojure

I have this code:

```clj
    (defn ^:dev/after-load mount-root []
      (re-frame/clear-subscription-cache!)
      (reagent/render [views/main-panel]
                      (.getElementById js/document "app")))
```

and in IntelliJ I want to duplicate the third line and then change it. Duplication works but the code won't compile because I need to add an additional single closing parentheses to the end of the code block:

```clj
    (defn ^:dev/after-load mount-root []
      (re-frame/clear-subscription-cache!)
      (reagent/render [views/main-panel]
      (reagent/render [views/second-panel] ;; duplicated line
                      (.getElementById js/document "app"))) ;; now missing closing parentheses
```

In IntelliJ, you can't add single brackets or parentheses to code so how can I duplicate the line and update the code so it doesn't throw a linting error / compiles?

Comment: Please clarify what happens if you put caret after "(.getElementById js/document "app")))" and type ")"?

Comment: @y.bedrovthanks - absolutely nothing happens. If I type `(`, I get `()`.

Comment: Is it possible to type ")" in other file types? Could you share idea.log ("Help | Show log in...") after restarting IDE?

Comment: @y.bedrov sure [here](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/284c0345acd669c59815780f78ed396720190903124403/d7024226b1269bb1144c9f74f10013f920190903124403/0a1aea) are the logs. I cannot type `) or ] or }` in any file, only the opposite which gives me a pair and when I try to delete one, it deletes both. It's obviously meant to behave like that to help you but coming from VS Code and Javascript it's basically stopping me from writing code.

Comment: could be [cursive/troubleshooting#i-can-t-close-my-parentheses](https://cursive-ide.com/userguide/troubleshooting.html#i-can-t-close-my-parentheses) - if cursive is indeed in use

Comment: In Emacs's paredit you can insert an unbalanced paren with `C-q(` (CTRL-q then (, or ], or }, et cetera). Maybe that works there too? Although I don't see the shortcut in Intellij's paredit on GitHub.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't delete Parenthesis in IntelliJ/Cursive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35091783/cant-delete-parenthesis-in-intellij-cursive)

Comment: It's very hard to find the above thread if you don't know what what paredit is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35091783/cant-delete-parenthesis-in-intellij-cursive) question.

Set `Use Structural Editing` to `None`.

IntelliJ→Preferences→Editor→General→Smart Keys→Clojure

Comment: Thanks for this. I imagine that feature is excellent for ppl who are comfortable with Clojure already, but when starting out and one has to google how to test a hello world function, it's a frickin pain in the butt.

Answer (score 3):

That's paredit.  Paredit works with the assumption that you never have unbalanced parentheses.  You are supposed to be working on *forms*, not on text.  Don't copy the line, copy the form.  There are many keyboard shortcuts to mark, navigate, delete, slurp, barf etc. entire forms.

If you happen to get into an unbalanced state, you often can return to a balanced state by copy-pasting the missing parentheses.

Comment: I have to copy and paste to get a single bracket? Thanks for answering the question but I think that's me done with IntelliJ unless you can disable it?

Comment: you can change the edit mode in the lower right corner (look for paredit).
Paredit takes some getting used to, but once you do it is great.
I want a paredit mode for Java now :)

Comment: Thanks both- sorted it!

Comment: Well, copy-pasting got you into the unbalanced mess, and copy-pasting gets you out again.

Comment: I don't think duplicating is copy-pasting? In every language parentheses stay balanced, so if you're trying to say that you shouldn't need to do it, you're wrong.

Comment: I didn't mean copy-pasting in a derogatory sense.  From the perspective of paredit, you should not copy _lines_ (or more generally, arbitrary _text_) but always complete _forms_ (i. e. atoms or lists), and it gives you the editing functions for that.

Comment: In @Mr.Robot's defense, I'd like to say that there is a problem in paredit here. It's understandable that users would encounter unbalanced parenthesis since paredit mode doesn't know how to handle copy-paste of arbitrary text yet copy-paste of arbitrary text is permitted. Then, to top it off, entering a single unbalanced parenthesis is forbidden. That's poor UI design. Either copy-paste of arbitrary text should be forbidden (and only forms by copyable) or entering single unbalanced parenthesis should be permitted. Or impl some intelligent way to handle pasting a block with unbalanced parens.